# How can you make calls with Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 with 4G/LTE?

Tags: samsung, calls, tablet

I am looking for a way to make calls from an Android tablet, namely `Samsung Galaxy Tab S3` which has `4G/LTE` support and thus has a SIM card slot. Do you know any ways of making calling from the Android tablet which are either official or not?

*I am open for rooting, installing custom ROMs and using external equipment like headphones.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call using cellular only and not data?  The device is on a data only plan even though it has a SIM card.

I suggest using Skype or Google Voice to call landlines, or Google Duo to call other Android users.  Both of these options will route your call over data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, it can receive phone calls. So, I assume there's a Phone app?

Source: http://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-s3-review-757782/

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding the sentence, looks like it's referring to the "*old SideSync app, which essentially virtualizes the phone in all of its glory on the tablet*" but has a prerequisite of being "*[o]wners of Samsung’s Galaxy smartphones.*" (looks like remote-controlling/syncing phone-to-tablet)